# How to correctly parse html and find the right element

Tags: python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_html(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout = 30)
        response.raise_for_status
        response.encoding = 'gbk'
        return response.content
    except:
        return "error found"

def get_content(url):
    html = get_html(url)
    contents = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    page = soup.find('ul', class_ = 'ulcl')
    lists = page.find_all('li')
    for l in lists:
        title = l.find('div', class_ = 'block').a.text
        release_time = l.find('span', class_ = 'state tody').text
        print(str(title) + '   ' + str(release_time))

def main(url):
    get_content(url)

base_url = 'http://it.ithome.com/apple/'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(base_url)
```

I'm recently learning python crawler which collects data of a certain website. The "get_html" method grabs the html content of a given website. The "get_content" method find all specific data that I want to find(E.g in this case I'm trying to find the content with the tag , which appears in the  tag. However, the problem appears on the line

```
title = l.find('div', class_ = 'block').a.text
```

The title is under a div block with class name 'block', and under an 'h2' and an 'a' tag. However, the compiler says 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'. What's the problem with that?

Comment: *with class name 'block', and under an 'h2' and an 'a' tag* - then why do you use `find(class_='block').a.text` and not `.h2.a.text` (or something like that, I'm no expert)?

Comment: Yeah I also tried that, but all those modifications don't work and I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

`l.find('div', class_ = 'block').a.text`

to

`l.find('div', class_ = 'block').find('h2').a.text`

Comment: It still doesn't work...The compiler says 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: log `l.find('div', class_ = 'block')` to see if it returns null

Comment: It does not return null and prints all of the <div> html text with class "block"

Answer (score 1):

try this. You need to install simplified_scrapy first. pip install simplified_scrapy

```
import requests
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 

def get_html(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout = 30)
        response.raise_for_status
        response.encoding = 'gbk'
        return response.content
    except:
        return "error found"

def get_content(url):
    html = get_html(url)
    if not html:
      print ('html is null')
      return
    contents = []
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
    page = doc.getElement('ul',attr='class',value='ulcl')
    lists = page.h2s # get all h2
    for l in lists:
        title = l.a.text
        url = l.a.href
        release_time = l.span.text
        print(str(title) + '   ' + str(release_time))

def main(url):
    get_content(url)

base_url = 'http://it.ithome.com/apple/'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(base_url)
```

Comment: pip install simplified_scrapy